How can I assign values to a SQLite database in python so that the data can be accessed from another python file?
I am trying to create a database using SQLite3. This database has values assigned in a python file however I want to be able to access the assigned data from another python file.
So far I have tried to create a database and added some values in two seperate python files:
import sqlite3 as sql

con = sql.connect("db_Persons.db")


cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Persons(
    UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Name TEXT,
    NumberPlate TEXT,
    Parking INTEGER    
)''')
con.close()

And the file, where I add data:
import sqlite3 as sql
con = sql.connect("db_Persons.db")

cur = con.cursor()
def setData():
    cur.execute("""
                INSERT INTO Persons (Name ,NumberPlate, Parking)
                VALUES( 'Alfred', 'DK12345', 0),
                ('Bent', 'DK45932', 0),
                ('Charlotte', 'DK84975',0),
                ('Dorte', 'DK98347', 0);
                """)
### Set and print the table 
setData()
Persons = cur.execute("""SELECT * from Persons""")
records = Persons.fetchall()
print("Total rows are:  ", len(records))
print("Printing each row")
for row in records:
    print("Id: ", row[0])
    print("Name: ", row[1])
    print("Licence Plate: ", row[2])
    print("Parking Spot: ", row[3])

When printing the table my data appears.
However the table seems to be empty in this other file:
import sqlite3 as sql

con = sql.connect("db_Persons.db")

cur = con.cursor()
Persons = cur.execute("""SELECT * from Persons""")
records = Persons.fetchall()
print("Total rows are:  ", len(records))
print("Printing each row")
for row in records:
    print("Id: ", row[0])
    print("Name: ", row[1])
    print("Licence Plate: ", row[2])
    print("Parking Spot: ", row[3])


Are you sure the two scripts are reading the same database? You used a relative path which means each script uses (or creates) an SQLite file in its current working directory. If you run the scripts with python myscript.py the working directory is the script's directory.

On top of that, SQLite does not allow multiple readers at the same time unless you use WAL mode. When that happens, modifications are stored in the Write Ahead Log file and applied to the data file periodically.

There's no call to con.commit() either, so any changes are lost

The code never calls con.commit() so all changes are lost. With the default settings, INSERT starts a new transaction implicitly.
The code should change to :
setData()
con.commit()

